# Replacing JSON strings with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, replace

I have a table column that's populated by documents and in the next column I've rendered what the file extension of that document is (i.e. .docx).

I want to be able to replace the file extension text with icon images that are locally stored `(folder/src/SiteAssets/Images/docx.gif)`.

Would I be able to work with the original code I have:

```
// -- Generating extension names -- //
    function docType(fileName) {
      return [fileName].filter(function() {
        return true;
      }).map(function(fileName) {
        return fileName.split('.').pop();
      }).pop();
    }
```

to replace the text with the icons? I was thinking of something like `if (extension===true), replace with icon.gif.` If need be I can get rid of this code and work with something else.

#### Loading document data:

```
$.noConflict();
    let tableRes = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return {
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name,
        "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
          return val.Label;
        }).join(";"),
        "Blank": "",
        "docImg": docType(obj.File.Name) // "Getting the docType of obj.File.Name"
      }
    })
```

#### Rendering table:

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        // { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Categories" }, // hidden
        { data: "docImg" },
        { data: "Titles" }
      ],
...etc
```

Comment: What exactly did you expect `return filter.toLowerCase().includes('doc' || 'docx') 
        || ('msg' || 'nrl') || ('pdf' || 'potx') 
        || ('ppt' || 'pptx') || ('rtf' || 'xls' || 'xlsx')` to do...?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it shows the documents' extensions as text. The table looks something like: | docx || File.docx | with the first column generating the extensions depending on what the document type is.

Comment: ^^^ I was just going to point that out.  That at the very least is a logical error.  @Bodrov no, `'doc' || 'docx'` will result in `doc` as that is the non falsy value.  It's never going to check for 'docx', nor any of the other values

Comment: That statement as-is, is essentially equivalent to `return true`

Comment: To elaborate on why that is effectively always true, `variable.includes(value) || ('a' || 'b')` is effectively `variable.includes(value) || 'a'` and `'a'` is always truthy

Comment: That function is equivalent to `function docType(fileName) { return fileName.split('.').pop(); }`

Comment: @Taplar @PatrickRoberts That's so much easier to read (and makes more sense). I removed the `filter.toLowerCase...etc` and updated my code sample.

Comment: Uhhh, you're missing the point.  The filter is pointless if you always return true.

Comment: It's also a code smell to filter over an array of one element.  Which is what ChrisG was pointing out.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/30Le9as8/

Comment: Have a look at the render option of datatables -> https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render